# Select only 2 days of Workdays?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have to select **only** 2 **workdays** after today at my datepicker.

Ps: If today is Friday, I can't select Saturday and Sunday, the datepicker have to skip to Monday and Thursday

I'm using PHP, JS, Bootstrap.

My current code:

```
$('.datepickerVencBoleto').datetimepicker({
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
    minDate: new Date(),
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
});

// DATEPICKER
$('.datepicker,.datepickerHojeMin').datetimepicker({
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
    showTodayButton: true,
    locale: moment.locale('pt-br'),
    showClear: true,
    showClose: true
});
```

The red circle means the days I have to enable. (Image Example)

[image: Example]

Comment: It got nothing to do with PHP, why PHP?

Comment: I don't know if your date plugin is the same, but with [this one](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#daysofweekdisabled) you can disable some specific dates or disable days of week, such as saturdays and sundays. If this is not your plugin, find the options of your's and look for this kind of configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`enabledDates`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#enableddates) to specify which days should be enabled.

You can determine which days should be enabled depending on the day of the week (see momentjs [`isoWeekday`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weekday/) for example).

Here a live sample using [`clone()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) and [`add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/):

```js
function next2Workdays(){
  var today = moment().startOf('day');
  if( today.isoWeekday()>=1 && today.isoWeekday()<=4 ){ // Today is Monday - Wednesday
    return [ today.clone(), today.clone().add(1, 'd') ];
   } else if( today.isoWeekday() == 5 ){  // Today is Friday
    return [ today.clone(), today.clone().add(3, 'd') ];
  } else if( today.isoWeekday() > 5 ){ // Today is Saturday or Sunday
    var startWeek = today.clone().startOf('isoWeek');
    var newWeek = startWeek.clone().add(1, 'week');
    return [ newWeek.clone().isoWeekday(1), newWeek.clone().isoWeekday(2)];
  }
}

$('.datepickerVencBoleto').datetimepicker({
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
    minDate: moment().startOf('day'),
    enabledDates: next2Workdays(),
    locale: 'pt-br',
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-sm-6'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date datepickerVencBoleto'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `minDate` should be used with `moment().startOf('day')` because if after you select the next day and want to select original date you wouldn't be able to do it